# Replace text using a regex only iff it is a field

Tags: regex, unix, awk, replace, sed

I have a comma delimited file that looks like the following

```
Start,Card,App,Description,Internet
2013-01-02 11:54:00,No Data,Off,Our system has  No Data,Off
2013-01-03 05:30:00,Visa,On,The monitoring system is Off,Off
2013-01-05 17:07:00,Master,Off,The system is On,On
2013-01-07 00:08:00,No Data,No Data,No Data,On
2013-01-09 04:40:00,Master,Off,System is Off,On
```

I want to replace `No Data` with `NA`, `Off` with `0`, and `On` with `1` only iff these words are fields, i.e. that is they have comma or beginning of newline or end of line. The required output is

```
Start,Card,App,Description,Internet
2013-01-02 11:54:00,NA,0,Our system has  No Data,0
2013-01-03 05:30:00,Visa,1,The monitoring system is Off,0
2013-01-05 17:07:00,Master,0,The system is On,1
2013-01-07 00:08:00,NA,NA,NA,1
2013-01-09 04:40:00,Master,0,System is Off,1
```

I tried for example,

```
sed 's/,Off,/,0,/g' test.txt
```

will only replace if the number of fields is greater than one or less than maximum number of fields. I also tried using look-arounds and leaving out header like

```
sed '2,$s/(?<=^|,)Off(?=$|,)/0/g' test.txt
```

I think this second command should work but didn't. Where did I go wrong? Thanks for the tips. Since the file is biggg, absolute indexing for columns like $4 is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` doesn't support lookarounds, `perl` to the rescue

```
$ perl -pe 'if($. > 1){ s/(^|,)\KOff(?=,|$)/0/g; s/(^|,)\KOn(?=,|$)/1/g; s/(^|,)\KNo Data(?=,|$)/NA/g; }' ip.txt
Start,Card,App,Description,Internet
2013-01-02 11:54:00,NA,0,Our system has  No Data,0
2013-01-03 05:30:00,Visa,1,The monitoring system is Off,0
2013-01-05 17:07:00,Master,0,The system is On,1
2013-01-07 00:08:00,NA,NA,NA,1
2013-01-09 04:40:00,Master,0,System is Off,1
```

Or, split input line on `,` and perform substitution on individual fields

```
$ perl -F, -lane 'if($. > 1){ foreach (@F){ s/^No Data$/NA/; s/^Off$/0/; s/^On$/1/ } } print join ",",@F' ip.txt 
Start,Card,App,Description,Internet
2013-01-02 11:54:00,NA,0,Our system has  No Data,0
2013-01-03 05:30:00,Visa,1,The monitoring system is Off,0
2013-01-05 17:07:00,Master,0,The system is On,1
2013-01-07 00:08:00,NA,NA,NA,1
2013-01-09 04:40:00,Master,0,System is Off,1
```

with `awk`

```
$ awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, 'NR>1{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ sub(/^No Data$/,"NA",$i); sub(/^Off$/,"0",$i); sub(/^On$/,"1",$i) } } 1' ip.txt 
Start,Card,App,Description,Internet
2013-01-02 11:54:00,NA,0,Our system has  No Data,0
2013-01-03 05:30:00,Visa,1,The monitoring system is Off,0
2013-01-05 17:07:00,Master,0,The system is On,1
2013-01-07 00:08:00,NA,NA,NA,1
2013-01-09 04:40:00,Master,0,System is Off,1
```

Answer (score 2):

In awk using ternary operators `(c ? "a" : "b")`:

```
$ awk -F, '{for(i=NF;i>0;i--) $i=($i=="No Data"?"NA":($i=="Off"?"0":($i=="On"?"1":$i)))} 1' OFS=, file
Start,Card,App,Description,Internet
2013-01-02 11:54:00,NA,0,Our system has  No Data,0
2013-01-03 05:30:00,Visa,1,The monitoring system is Off,0
2013-01-05 17:07:00,Master,0,The system is On,1
2013-01-07 00:08:00,NA,NA,NA,1
2013-01-09 04:40:00,Master,0,System is Off,1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(split($i,a,"Off|On|No Data| +")==2) {sub(/No Data/,"NA",$i);sub(/Off/,"0",$i);sub(/On/,"1",$i)}}1' OFS="," file
```

Comment: this doesn't work for all cases, for example if fields are at start of line.. also, what if there is a field like `,Off xyz`?

Comment: that still doesn't work if field has other text than pattern to match

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/(^|,)No Data(,|$)/\1NA\2/g;s/(^|,)Off(,|$)/\10\2/g;s/(^|,)On(,|$)/\11\2/g;ta' file
```

Use back references with alternation to replace required string and delimiters.

N.B. Delimiters either side of a required string must be tested twice hence the loop back to the place holder `:a`.